# Dynamic columns in data table componet in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, datatable, kibana

Good afternoon,
My situation is the next. I have loaded the data in elasticsearch. I have managed to make a data table where I group by department and add all the prices of the department. the result is a column with each department per row and another column with the sum of the price of each department. then there is another data that is the year. This year I want it to come into play so that when I select a year now I get a column with the sum of departments but only for that year. If I select two different years I want two columns to be shown, one with the one year's number and the other with the sum of the other year. Some help?

The query is the next:

```
SELECT Gcfn09(tr6200.tr62feciniact)           curso, 
       trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) mes,
       ad7400.ad74descentro                   centro, 
       ad0200.ad02desdpto                     dpto, 
       pr1200.pr12desactividad                tipo_actividad,  
       tr6200.tr62puntos                      importe, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'OCTUBRE' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'SEPTIEMBRE' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'NOVIEMBRE' 
       THEN 'Q1' 
         WHEN Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'DICIEMBRE' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'ENERO' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'FEBRERO' THEN 
         'Q2' 
         WHEN Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'MARZO' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'ABRIL' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'MAYO' THEN 
         'Q3' 
         WHEN Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'JUNIO' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'JULIO' 
               OR Trim(To_char(tr6200.tr62feciniact, 'MONTH')) = 'AGOSTO' THEN 
         'Q4' 
       END                                    AS cuatrimestre 
FROM   tr6200, 
       pr0200, 
       pr0100, 
       pr1200, 
       ad0200, 
       ad7400, 
       ci3200, 
       ci1300 
WHERE  tr6200.pr01codactuacion = pr0200.pr01codactuacion 
       AND tr6200.pr01codactuacion = pr0100.pr01codactuacion 
       AND pr0100.pr12codactividad = pr1200.pr12codactividad 
       AND pr0200.ad02coddpto = ad0200.ad02coddpto 
       AND ad0200.ad74codcentro = ad7400.ad74codcentro 
       AND tr6200.ci32codtipecon = ci3200.ci32codtipecon 
       AND tr6200.ci32codtipecon = ci1300.ci32codtipecon 
       AND tr6200.ci13codentidad = ci1300.ci13codentidad 
ORDER  BY curso, 
          mes
```

now i created four scripted field in kibana:

[image]

I have created four columns in a data table, each with the sum of a script field.
Then I created a bucket with the department field.

What I want to achieve is that if I filter by course, only the filtered columns appear. columns with zero value do not want to show them

[image]

Comment: Can you post your query, sample data and desired output?

Comment: I have  edited the post

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest thing to do here is to remove metrics 4 and 5 here?

Comment: no, but i want remove columns depending the filter. if in the filter i select ther 3rd and fourth column i want deleted the first and the second for example

Comment: those are row filters, if you can switch the query to make Departamentos as columns and years as rows then you can filter out those unwanted years